# Error binding parameter : sqllite 3 interface error

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.x

Been trying to get the above error of for ages, cant figure it out. Tried the other solutions here, but to no use. Do i have to change it to tuple? How do i support the ? values, as the columns dont have names in my db. Cant figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def Update_db_table():
    global File_CSV


    # Open the csv and then covert it for SQL and place in table
    Open_CSV = reader(open(File_CSV, 'r',encoding="utf-8"), delimiter=',')
    print (Open_CSV)
    for row in Open_CSV:
        to_db = [(row[0], "utf8"),(row[1], "utf8"), (row[2], "utf8"), (row[3], "utf8"),(row[4], "utf8"),(row[5], "utf8"),(row[6], "utf8"),(row[7], "utf8")]

        RFID_db.execute("INSERT INTO 'All_Students' (First_Name, Last_Name, RFID_Number, Student_Age, Gender, Cohort, Non_Champion_Points, Champion_Points) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", to_db)
    connection.commit()
```

This is part of code returning the error.

The traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\tejas\Desktop\Beta_version> python Admin_Program.py
['Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red']
30
33
25
24
C:/Users/tejas/Desktop/Beta_version/CSV/test population.csv
<_csv.reader object at 0x02BEC1F0>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Admin_Program.py", line 321, in <lambda>
    Update_table = Button(Add_CSV, text = 'Update Table', command = lambda: Update_db_table())
  File "Admin_Program.py", line 210, in Update_db_table
    RFID_db.execute("INSERT INTO 'All_Students' (First_Name, Last_Name, RFID_Number, Student_Age, Gender, Cohort, Non_Champion_Points, Champion_Points) VALUES ((?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?));", to_db)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Thanks,

Cheers!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these `"utf8"` strings?

Comment: I was hoping they would be encoded in that format of utf-8, basically I am trying to connect the database to the program, and use some tables in tkinter to update them. But currently this one is the bone of contention.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#introduction).

Comment: so basically we dont need a Utf-8 string as its default. right?